# return json in column-wise format

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to return json in column-wise format

Suppose the **User** table has 3 columns `(Name, age, location)`,

#### User Table

```
Jack, 18, Taiwan
Mary, 27, Japan
```

Expected JSON response format (by columnar)

```
{
 name:["Jack", "Mary"],
 age: [18, 27],
 location: ["Taiwan", "Japan"]
}
```

How to finish it on Rails ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
data = {
  name: User.pluck(:name),
  age: User.pluck(:age),
  location: User.pluck(:location)
}

render json: data
```

but be advised, this will query the database 3 times!

**EDIT**: If you want to do it all in 1 Query, do the following:

```
data = {
  name: [],
  age: [],
  location: []
}

User.pluck(:name, :age, :location).each do |u|
  data[:name] << u[0]
  data[:age] << u[1]
  data[:location] << u[2]
end

render json: data
```